# Can I download Ubuntu for Android to my mobile device?

Tags: android, tablet, ubuntu-for-android, ubuntu-touch

My question is already in the title. I want to buy a tablet but I want to work with OpenOffice as well. So in combination with a monitor and a dock it would be possible.
But can I download Ubuntu for Android somewhere?

Comment: Example on what is needed: Ubuntu on a Transformer Prime: http://androlinux.com/android-ubuntu-development/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-rooted-transformer-prime/ Warranty voided ofcourse since you need to root your device. It's not as easy as a normal install.

Comment: Do you mean this? http://linuxonandroid.org/

Comment: I've found a very useful resource concerning this topic, try going to http://linuxonandroid.blogspot.com/ Make sure to check the compatibility list concerning the device which you're planning on installing your linux-based platform. The list incorporates both Phones and Tablets

Answer (score 4):

No, its not possible now. But you can buy Android tablet and write Ubuntu to the tablet. Also one company selling ubuntu tablet. I already tested Ubuntu in Samsung Galaxy S2 - it works but screen is small. Another way, why not to use Android itself for this?
I'm using Polaris office and Google Drive for documents. Connect your tablet to the monitor using HDMI and enjoy it. I think Ubuntu for Android will be available in Ubuntu 14.04 version. Mark Shuttleworth (CEO of Canonical) sayed that Ubuntu for TV,Tablet and Android will be available in Ubuntu 14.04 (Next LTS version)

For Example There Official Ubuntu for SmartQ T20: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/06/ubuntu-12-04-firmware-released-for-smartq-t20-tablet

Comment: you tested ubuntu for android or running ubuntu via vnc?

Comment: ubuntu for android (from canonical) not for public. We can only test it as dual boot in phone (android and ubuntu, there is special bootloaders) or with vnc with running in terminal for android. (it opens sh file that will run ubuntu.img/ (Maveric)

Answer (score 1):

No you can't. Ubuntu is integrated deeply with android kernel in Ubuntu for andriod. It is not like installation of one application. The tablet/ phone   manufacturer must do it and it would be preinstalled in tablet/phone.

Comment: Ubuntu was on a Transformer before Asus unlocked the system ;) But you do need special firmware.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu's video for *Ubuntu for android* makes it sound like you can use a pre-existing smart phone with a multi-core processor and install it, but I have not seen anything that allows you to install it on to a phone yourself.  Their contact option is geared toward smart phone manufacturers.

Answer (score 0):

You can Install Ubuntu for Mobile from here

[Ubuntu Mobile](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install)