# Ubuntu For Android!

Tags: android

Pl. tell me how to install Ubuntu on Android Tablet or Phone.   Another thing is i'm not using Ubuntu Desktop and I'm using Windows. So tell me what to do to install Ubuntu on Android.

Thanks...

Comment: Can you clarify if you want Ubuntu Touch or Ubuntu for Android?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a link to ubuntu's wiki for the touch version with the instructions for a linux machine. Unfortunately I believe some steps require Linux to install ubuntu to a tablet.

[Here](http://androlinux.com/android-ubuntu-development/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-rooted-transformer-prime/) is the link for the Install based on a Trasnformer tablet but it must be rooted and I don't know your device but good luck!

For Windows, You must make sure that the Android Developer Bridge is installed as well.
I found these instructions [http://]androidforums.com/lg-spirit-4g/692656-install-adb-windows-ubuntu-12-04-12-10-a.html (Not 10 rep so I cannot post two links.) for making that possible. First Forum post, second guide.

Unless you have a Nexus device though I would recommend **NOT** pursuing this avenue. [Source](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install#Supported_devices_and_codenames)

Comment: That's for Ubuntu Touch not Ubuntu for Android.

Comment: Correct. I didn't realize they had a separate version for phones now. I revised my google-fu and found an answer from [this Question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/181384/can-i-download-ubuntu-for-android-to-my-mobile-device)